# Create a canvas and toggle images based on selection

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to have images populate (only ever one) based on a drop down selection from a Select switch. The images need to allow for drawing over (which is all set up) but I can't seem to figure out the html...

```
<img draggable="true" src="URL to image" crossorigin="anonymous"> <!-- small image that I want to be able to drag onto the canvas -->

<select name="map" id="map" onchange="setImage(this);" class="control control-lg">
<optgroup label="First">
<option value="URL to Image">Option 1</option>
</optgroup>
</select>

<div class="canvas-container">
<img src="" name="image-swap" /> <!-- Image that populates when first option is selected -->
<script>
function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}  
</script>
</div>
```

This doesn't allow for my other image to be dragged into the canvas or drawn overtop. I probably because I don't understand canvas too well.

EDIT: The CSS .canvas-container just specifies a width of 100%

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't use canvas here.
It's a pure Img tag but this is still possible to render an image from the selected option. One thing is that you need a couple of options because otherwise, you don't trigger onchange event.

```html
<option value="volvo.jpg">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab.jpg">Saab</option>
<option value="mercedes.jpg">Mercedes</option>
```

and now every option change should replace src for this particular image.

Rendering it on canvas would be much different.
First, you have to create

```html
<canvas>
```

tag.

You can do it in your HTML code or from js eg:

```js
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.setAttribute('width', 132);
canvas.setAttribute('height', 150);
```

To render img you need 2d context on the canvas and img path.
Quick basic implementation would look like:

```js
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.drawImage('yourimagesrc.jpg',
                300, 700);
}
```

Here are docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: So how would I swap the images based on selection event change? I tried:
<canvas width="985" height="554" src="URL to image" name="image-swap" style="user-select: none;"></canvas>
But the image will no longer show. This was by replacing the <img> tag